# How can I have editors select which blocks to be displayed in what order per page?

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I have taken on a site that has hard coded page urls in it's page.html.twig for loading specific sidebar blocks based on the url for related content.
eg:

```
  {% if 'frozen' in url|render|render %}
              {# shows these blocks and in this order #}
              <aside id="sidebar">
                  {{ block_chooserecipes }}
                  {{ block_healthbenefits }}
              </aside>
```

Is there a way to create a content type field that will load the sidebar blocks that the editor wishes to include with their main content?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a checkbox field for sidebar block in your content type. Once user selects a set of block to be visible, check those checkbox values in your page.html.twig. Print only those blocks which are checked by user.

Comment: I like this suggestion as it can be implemented with minimal effort. I assume I could use the following condition: ```{% if node.field_checkbox.value %}```

Answer (score 0):

First you can create an entity reference field node ->> blocks.
Then, create a custom Block visibility condition, like for example web/core/modules/language/src/Plugin/Condition/Language.php
Where you can check if the block belongs to the node you are in at the moment.